# Error: could not open D:\Java2\lib\i386\jvm.cfg

Tags: java, windows

I got this error `Error: could not open D:\Java2\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'` when I type `java -version` in command in Window 10.

In my system variable, my `JAVA_HOME` is `D:\Java` and under environment variable, I have set to below:

[image]

Not sure why it is still looking for `D:\Java2`?

Comment: You might want to give some context for your question. What were you trying to do when you ran into that error? Is there some code associated with this error? You've been on Stack Overflow long enough to realize that people can't read your mind, so if you want an answer, you're going to have to supply some details.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, I didn't run any code. I just want to make sure I can run 'java -version' but it ran into that error.

Comment: Reinstall Java using a distribution with an installer

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, ok after uninstall and reinstall, it works now.